# Is there a way to use anchors and lookarounds in regex together?

Tags: regex

I'm very new to using regex.

I've tried to combine an anchor and lookaround to grab the start time for day 2.

Text:

```
8/9/2021 8:00 AM to 6:00 PM
8/23/2021 8:00 AM to 5:00 PM
```

Expressions that I've tried:

```
\n[0-9]{1,2}\:[0-9]{2}\s[A-Z]{2}(?= to)

^[0-9]{1,2}\:[0-9]{2}\s[A-Z]{2}(?= to)

([0-9]{1,2}\:[0-9]{2}\s[A-Z]{2}){3}
```

In the end, I'd have a breakdown like this:

| date_day1 | start_day1 | end_day1 | date_day2 | start_day2 | end_day2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8/9/2021 | 8:00 AM | 6:00 PM | 8/23/2021 | 8:00 AM | 5:00 PM |

Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

This will match the start time for day 2:

```
(?<=to [0-9]:[0-9]{2} [AP]M\s)[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{4} ([0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2} [AP]M)
```

- the lookbehind `(?<=to [0-9]:[0-9]{2} [AP]M\s)` matches the end of day 1
- `[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{4}`  matches the date of day 2
- `([0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2} [AP]M)` matches start of day 2 as group

You can get it much shorter, depending on how your input might change:

```
(?<=M\s)[0-9\/]* ([0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2} [AP]M)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried out both options and it didn't work. On RegExR, it said that it was due to the "Positive Lookbehind".

https://regexr.com/6308t

Comment: It's because there is a line break between day 1 and 2. Was it intended? The lookbehind shouldn't be a problem. You can still remove it (keeping what's inside), it won't changed the content of your captured group.

Comment: I changed the regex so that it works with line breaks

Comment: Apologies, looking back at what I wrote, I failed to add the second line.
I've updated the question/request to reflect this. Thank you again for the response. Is there a way to only grab the times from the second line (separatly)? I'm using this one to grab the date \n[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{4}

Comment: Sure. Put everything else in the lookbehind: `(?<=M\s[0-9\/]* )([0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2} [AP]M)` for start time.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are not matching the date part `8/9/2021` before the time.

- Using an anchor `^` can also match day 1.
- This pattern `([0-9]{1,2}\:[0-9]{2}\s[A-Z]{2}){3}` matches 3 times the time part like `5:00 PM5:00 PM5:00 PM` but that is not what you want

You can match a newline `\n` and then the date part followed by capturing the time and match the following  `to`

This does not make sure that the line before is also in the same format.

```
\n\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4} ([0-9]{1,2}\:[0-9]{2} [A-Z]{2}) to
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iKErLX/1)

If both lines should be of the same format (without using multiline)

```
^\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4} [0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2} [A-Z]{2} to \d{1,2}:\d{1,2} [AP]M\n\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4} ([0-9]{1,2}\:[0-9]{2} [A-Z]{2}) to
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rGuPQL/1)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is there a way to only grab the times from the second line (separately)? I'm using this one to grab the date `\n[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{4}`

Comment: @cddouglass What tool or language are you using? In the example, the second time is in capture group 1.